# Multiple hover effect with multi element css

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to hover in my class `onHover` and adding a display effect  in `span.box`but not work any idea ?

```css
.onHover {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}
.onHover:hover + span.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="onHover">
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="image"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `+` is the adjacent sibling selector and the span is a child, not a sibling

Comment: You don't need `+` as it is not a sibling. Please remove `+`: `.onHover:hover span.box`. Closing this as a typo!

Comment: @PraveenKumar is right.  remove the +

Comment: @NenadVracar not working without + !

Comment: @nevergiveup Show your full code then. Create a Stack Snippet (press Ctrl + M).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fVgrp/

Comment: You'll also probably want to add transition effects due to you trying to change the size.

Comment: Retracting the close vote as it is not a typo alone.

Comment: @nevergiveup Sorry buddy. See my working answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are **applying it for `inline` element**. You need to set the `display` for `span`. Moreover, `+` is used for selecting siblings, and not children. Either remove it or replace it with `>`:

```css
.onHover {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}
.onHover:hover span.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="onHover">
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="image"></span>
</div>
```

The `width` and `height` can be set only for `block` and `inline-block` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Besides removing the `+` which is the adjacent sibling selector and here the `span` is a child.

The `:hover`  won't work as `span` is displayed as `inline`

```css
.onHover {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}
.onHover:hover span.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="onHover">
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="image"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pseudo element `:hover` like this

```
span.box: hover{width:300px; height:20px; background:lightgray; margin:10px 0;}
```

Comment: Man did you even use code formatting? This doesn't work anyways.